# I'm at a dead end. SQL Query to get the last replied username and time stamp

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

This is the query I am trying to get to work.

```
SELECT  
    t.id AS topic_id,
    t.title AS topic_title,
    t.content AS topic_content,
    t.created_at AS topic_created_at,
    t.updated_at AS topic_updated_at,
    t.user_id AS topic_user_id,
    c.id AS comment_id,
    c.content AS comment_content,
    c.created_at AS comment_created_at,
    max_c.username AS comment_username,
    u.username AS topic_username
FROM   
    topics t
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         c2.topic_id, c2.created_at, u2.username 
     FROM 
         comments c2
     JOIN 
         users u2 ON c2.user_id = u2.id
     JOIN 
         topics t2 ON c2.topic_id = t2.id
     ORDER BY 
         c2.created_at desc) max_c ON t.id = max_c.topic_id
JOIN 
    comments c ON max_c.created_at = c.created_at
JOIN 
    users u ON u.id = t.user_id
ORDER BY 
    c.created_at DESC
```

Pretty sure this part of the query is not correct:

```
SELECT 
    c2.topic_id, c2.created_at, u2.username 
FROM 
    comments c2
JOIN 
    users u2 ON c2.user_id = u2.id
JOIN 
    topics t2 ON c2.topic_id = t2.id
ORDER BY 
    c2.created_at desc
```

That query currently displays the following. But I want to group by `created_at` or what ever is suitable so we only get the latest replied on topic.

If you can help this would be amazing I've spent about 5 hours trying to write this so far...

I've attached my table migrations below.

```
# Dump of table comments
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `comments_ibfk_2` (`topic_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `comments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`topic_id`) REFERENCES `topics` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



# Dump of table topics
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `topics_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



# Dump of table users
# ------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'NOT NULL',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'NOT NULL',
  `password` char(60) DEFAULT 'NOT NULL',
  `admin` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: To improve the (already quite good) quality of your Question, please add a description of what your whole statement is meant to achieve as well as a description of the intended function of parts of the statement.  Also, please show the structure of your tables with sample data, and perhaps expand your table creation script with statements to insert this data.  Also, please show how you would like the output to appear based on the sample data.  Also, you refer to the current output of your statement, but so not actually show that output.  And are you using `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc.?

Comment: Can a `User` start a `Topic` but *not* post a `Comment` at that time?

Comment: Can we assume that two `Users` can not post a `Comment` on the same `Topic` at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question the problem you are having is the subquery should return only the last username and timestamp, but returns all instead. That being the case you could just use LIMIT 1 after the order by to have desired result.

```
    SELECT c2.topic_id, c2.created_at,u2.username 
    FROM comments c2
    JOIN users u2 ON c2.user_id = u2.id
    JOIN topics t2 ON c2.topic_id = t2.id
    ORDER BY c2.created_at desc
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT topics.id AS topic_id,
       topics.title AS topic_title,
       topics.content AS topic_content,
       topics.created_at AS topic_created_at,
       topics.updated_at AS topic_updated_at,
       topicsUsers.user_id AS topic_user_id,
       topicsUsers.username AS topic_username,
       comments.id AS comment_id,
       comments.content AS comment_content,
       maxCreatedAt AS comment_created_at,
       commentsUsers.user_id AS comment_user_id
       commentsUsers.username AS comment_username,
FROM topics
JOIN ( SELECT topic_id AS topic_id,
              MAX( comments.created_at ) AS maxCreatedAt,
       FROM comments
       GROUP BY topic_id
     ) maxCreatedAtFinder ON topics.id = maxCreatedAtFinder.topic_id
JOIN comments ON maxCreatedAtFinder.maxCreatedAt = comments.created_at
             AND maxCreatedAtFinder.topic_id = topics.id
JOIN users AS topicsUsers ON users.id = topics.user_id
JOIN users AS commentsUsers ON users.id = comments.user_id
ORDER BY maxCreatedAt DESC
```

As best I can tell from your Question, you are looking for a list that shows the details of each `topic` (including the `user` details of the `user` who initiated the `Topic`) along with the most recent `comment` for that `Topic` and the details of the `user` who posted that `comment`.

My statement follows a similar structure to the statement you supplied.  I have removed from the subquery the `JOIN` to `topics` since the `topic_id` is the only detail from `topics` that we want for the subquery, and `topic_id` can also be obtained from `comments`.

Obtaining the details of the `user` who posted the most recent `comment` for the `Topic` would complicate the grouping and result in more joins being performed than if we joined `Comments` to `Users` outside of the subquery.  All the subquery really needs to do is obtain the most recent value of `created_at` for each `Topic`.  As such I have removed the `JOIN` to `Users` and the associated field selections.

In the main statement I have maintained the `INNER JOIN` of the subquery to `topics`, which effectively appends the maximum value of `created_at` from `comments` to its corresponding record from `topics`.

I then take the resulting dataset and join it to `comments` in such a way that a `topic` and its associated most recent value of `created_at` from `comments` has the contents of each `comment` for that `topic` *with* that `created_at` value appended to it.  Please note that whilst unlikely it is possible for two `comments` belonging to a `topic` to be created at the same time and thus to have the same value of `created_at`.  Both such records will be joined to the dataset being formed.  In the absence of instructions to the contrary I have assumed that is desired behaviour and have allowed it.

I then take the resulting dataset and `JOIN` it to two instances of `users`, one based on the `topic_id` and the other based on the `user_id` for the `comment`.  This has the effect of appending to each record in our dataset the `user` details for the `user` who created the `Topic` and the `user` details of the `user`(s) who posted the most recent `comment`(s).

This final dataset is then sorted into chronological order, starting with the most recent record(s).

The desired fields are then selected and returned by the statement.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.